# How to write injective proofs for functions like $e^x$ and $tan(x)$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

How do you prove that functions like $e^x$ or $tan(x)$ are injective?

For example, if I wanted to demonstrate that $f(x)=e^x$ for $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow (0,\infty)$, I would proceed like any other "Injective Proof" and say:

Let $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

$e^{x_1}=e^{x_2}$

$log_e (e^{x_1}) = log_e (e^{x_2})$

$x_1 = x_2$

However, I then think to myself..."*I just used an inverse function to demonstrate that the function was injective...*

This strikes me as inherently circular, for a function cannot have an inverse unless it is first injective (and also surjective, of course).

A similar example could be given for $tan(x)$ where I would  subsequently use $arctan()$. (assuming $f$ is defined as $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$)

Any advice?

Comment: If a continuous function is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on an interval, it is injective on this interval. A sufficient condition is that the derivate is positive (or negative) on the interval with possible isolated exceptional points.

Comment: $\tan$ is not injective, though...

Comment: If I make the domain (0,1) it is, I believe.

Comment: @pyon But it is not continuous either.

Comment: I made the appropriate clarification that I think should address your comments.

Comment: You are correct: the restriction of $\tan$ to $(0,1)$ is injective, indeed. (But strictly speaking, this restriction is another function.)

Comment: What about $e^{x_{1}}=e^{x_{2}}$ implies $e^{x_{1}-x_{2}} =1 $?

Comment: @Peter: $\tan$ is a continuous function. The issue here is that $\tan$'s domain is not an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can show that a function is monotone: i.e. $x<y$ implies $f(x)<f(y)$ (or with $>$).

A differentiable function whose derivative carries a sign is monotone, which I invite you to prove.

Show that a continuous injective function must be monotone.

Comment: What do you mean by the word "sometimes". Are there certain injective functions where it is not always easy to demonstrate a  monotone behavior?

Comment: Cramer: Yes: You can for example define the function: f(x)=x if the Riemann hypothesis is true, f(x)=0 if it is false. Then f is monotone if and only if the Riemann hypothesis is true. But this is an open problem: noone knows. Of course this doesn't directly show up in calculus, but if you take very complicated compositions of elementary functions, it can be hard to see if a function is monotone.